# Android YouTube v3 api - video set volume

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

How can I set my YouTubePlayer volume? 
And, is it any option to change the onPause method ? I want to keep my player playing, but the super.onPause() , stop the player every time.

Answer (score 0):

1) According to [this document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary) I can't find anything regarding to volume. So, I think "changing volume is impossible".

2) According to [PlaybackEventListener](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener), `onPaused` called when playback is paused, either due to `pause()` or user action.

You say "the super.onPause() , stop the player every time.", so I guess that a part of `YouTubePlayerView` in your layout is covered by something(see below pickture)

[image]

Comment: Hi @vandaics, Thanks for the response, what do you mean by: "so I guess that a part of YouTubePlayerView in your layout is covered by something."?

Comment: I will update my answer with an image for you to understand what I want to say.